# Testing channelHandlers in netty

Tags: netty

I'm trying to test something super simple in Netty to figure out how EmbeddedChannel works.  My handler looks like this:

```
@Component
@Sharable
public class VersionServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private VersionService versionService;

    @Autowired
    public VersionServerHandler(VersionService versionService) {
        this.versionService = versionService;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        boolean isSupported = versionService.isVersionSupported((VersionRequest) msg.getVersion());

        // more logic
        ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
    }
```

My test looks like:

```
 @Mock 
    private VersionService versionService;

    @Test
    public void testChannelRead() {
        EmbeddedChannel embeddedChannel = new EmbeddedChannel(new VersionServerHandler(versionService); 
        ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.buffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            buf.writeByte(i);
        }
        ByteBuf dup = buf.duplicate();

        boolean test = embeddedChannel.writeInbound(dup.retain());
        // test is false
```

I'm just trying to write bytes to the EmbeddedChannel with VersionServerHandler in it like in the netty example, but `test` is false isntead of true.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `writeInbound(...)` will only return `true` if the message hit the end of the pipeline. To check what you want to check you would call `writeInbound(...)` and then use `readOutbound()` and check that it not return `null`. Also `channel.finish()` should return `true`.

Comment: I thought that writeInbound() would return true if there was something to read in the embeddedChannel?  So I thought that writeInbound in this scenario would return true?

Comment: like I said it will only return true if something hit the end of the pipeline and so can be read via `readInbound()`